# Rename an Azure Storage Table programmatically

Tags: azure-table-storage

Is there a way to rename an Azure Storage Table programmatically?

I regularly delete Tables with data that's not used anymore but I might start to save it for longer. To avoid messing with a working system (it's checking for those tables to generate data) I would like to just rename them or do some sort of copy instead of just deleting.

Is there a way to do this with Azure Storage Tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that someone has answered this elsewhere now:
[Rename Azure Storage Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322535/rename-azure-storage-table)

Currently it isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to rename Azure Storage table.
The only thing you can do is to download all entities from the table you want to rename and then upload them to new table with your new name

Answer (score -2):

Try,

```
EXEC sp_rename 'oldTableName', 'newTableName'
```

Note: This simple method uses the built-in stored procedure to do the renaming.  You can use the same method to rename columns inside the table (use table.column)

Comment: Thank you, but I believe there's a misunderstanding here. I'm not trying to do renaming in SQL Server/Database but on Azure Storage Tables which is something different and to my knowledge do not have that option.